# Adding new events by dragging from elemensts on the page

Tags: fullcalendar

I have some draggable div tags (using jquery) on my page, and would like to be able to drag that tag onto a day in the calander, and add a new event.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

here is the feature request for it:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=238

however, i did make this feature for a single client (under os license) and have yet to roll it into a release. the api is sort of sloppily done, but it works:

http://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/tree/fcdraggable

download the branch and run examples/external-event-drag.html

im sorry but i can't spend any time w/ u trying to get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Cool!  Does this rely on tweaks to the 1.4.4 code, or would it work with the 1.4.5?  I tried to compare the 1.4.4 standard and 1.4.5 code vs the 'draggable' example files but they are significantly different.  I could not tell if it's specifically different for the draggable example or not.